# How to Make Datepicker Comply with WCAG 2.0?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, accessibility, wcag

Recently I have received a project to make a webpage comply with WCAG 2.0 Level A. The part that I am running into a problem at the moment is the datepicker component. The datepicker component allows the user to select the date in two ways. One way is to manually type in a date, for example, 04/06/2014. The other way is to select the small image beside it and a calendar would basically pop-up and the user can select the date from there.

While researching over the web, some people have suggested that we do not have to make the image part of the datepicker component accessible since the text-field itself provides an alternative for accessibility. Is this acceptable (**First Question**)?

If this is the right way to go, how do I make it so that accessibility technology like screen reader would ignore the image icon (**Second Question**)? I have also tried to research for this issue. Basically, if it was just an image, we could set the "alt" attribute to null. But this image is actually embedded inside an "anchor" tag (which makes the image click-able) therefore this practice is invalid (verified by achecker.ca).

- Update: [HTML5 Accessibility: aria-hidden and role=”presentation”](http://john.foliot.ca/aria-hidden/) answers the second question

Any thoughts would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question depends on what the usability reason is for showing a visual calendar? If you are showing it so that users can select a date based on use cases like "first Friday in Month X" or something similar, then simply providing a text input, while making the page at least usable, does not make the page functionally equivalent for screen reader and keyboard-only users and therefore does not pass WCAG 2.

Your answer to the second question that you posted, works for screen readers (in terms of removing the aforementioned functionality) but it now presents a problem to sighted keyboard-only users. You are therefore still not WCAG 2 compliant.

Making date pickers accessible, while difficult, is possible. Are you using the jQuery UI datepicker?